# Conversão de palavras em números e vice versa

Tags: php

Existe algum modo de transformar palavras inteiras em números únicos de forma que eu possa fazer o processo inverso caso necessário? Como se fosse um identificar único daquela palavra, tipo

```
Palavra -> Numero -> Palavra
oi -> 09368 -> oi
```

Comment: Dê mais detalhes de como isto deve ser feito. Mostre o que já fez.

Comment: Seria algo como [Como transformar dígitos numéricos em números por extenso?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5945/91), [Como converter número em float para número por extenso no PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99460/91) ?

Comment: @bigown não fiz nada a principio, gostaria de saber se existe algo pré definido para PHP ou existente, caso não, o que me vem a cabeça seria criar array com letras com códigos pré definidos tipo A => 01, B = 02....

Comment: @rray não é o que eu procuro.

Comment: @Elaine precisa estabelecer os critérios, há uma relação direta? Os números são calculados pela palavra? É só um código previamente determinado?

Comment: Huum vc quer cifrar uma palavra em número e depois descifrar? talvez de p usar os códigos ASCII

Comment: @bigown não há relação direta com a palavra, é como uma placa de carro que identifica aquele carro especifico.

Comment: @rray será? eu tentei usar as funções `ord` e `chr` porém elas só vão com um caractere por vez, e eu precisaria de um número inteiro representando a palavra de forma que eu possa decifra-la como vc mesmo disse.

Comment: @Elaine estes códigos são números mesmo ou são textos numéricos?

Comment: @Elaine seus comentários são contraditórios. Defina o que realmente quer, tem relação direta ou não tem?

Comment: @bigown é necessário que sejam números (int). Talvez eu tenha entendido mal, o número da palavra deve ser capaz de indicar qual palavra o gerou. Compreendes?

Comment: @Elaine qual é o critério para chegar neste código? Eu já tinha montado a resposta sem ter a relação direta.

Comment: @bigown nada em especifico, realizando a função já basta, tens idéias de como fazer?

Comment: @Elaine Não. Tem inúmeras maneiras de fazer isto. Precisa ter um critério. Precisa ter regras de como esse número deve ser achado. Tem que ter as restrições do que pode ou não fazer. Como lidar com as colisões, só para dar um exemplo.

Comment: @bigown não tenho idéia sobre esses pontos, como eu disse "o que me vem a cabeça seria criar array com letras com códigos pré definidos tipo A => 01, B = 02...."

Comment: Dei uma resposta baseado nisto, mas se deseja calcular, teria que ter critérios.

Comment: @Elaine vc poderia especificar na pergunta algumas restrições em relação aos números que serão gerados a partir de uma palavra, por exemplo: Pode ser numero negativo? Existe um numero máximo ou minimo?

Comment: @Elaine eu faria isto com um calculo matemático, para que a partir de cada palavra eu geraria um numero para ela, calculando as vogais e as consoantes, existe outras formas, porem esta pode ser uma opção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Vou manter esta resposta aqui porque pode ajudar alguém, a pergunta foi melhor esclarecida nos comentários e o problema era outro. Mas o outro não pode ser resolvido sem ter critérios para defini-lo, o que pode inclusive ser complicado se precisar de uma conversão para número único. Mesmo que se garanta que só pode existir palavras (portanto curtas), a quantidade de combinações para evitar repetição é tão grande que é melhor deixar o texto mesmo.

Eu imagino que o que deseja seja o dicionário, ou *array* associativo, como este recurso é mais conhecido no PHP:

```
$palavras = array(
    "oi" => 09368,
    "tchau"   => 01234,
    "palavra" => 34986,
    "abobrinha" => 72494);
$codigo = $palavras["oi"]; //busca rápida
$palavra = array_search(01234, $palavras); //busca lenta
```

A primeira por fazer através de [funções *hash*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash), é muito rápido (complexidade O(1) ). Já a busca pelo valor é lenta (complexidade O(n) ). É possível obter complexidade O(log n) que é próxima da O(1) se o *array* estiver garantidamente com os valores ordenados. Aí é possível fazer uma busca binária.

Ainda é possível, se a memória não for um impedimento, ter um segundo *array* com os valores invertidos. Aí é possível fazer a busca em O(1) em ambos. Assim:

```
$palavras = array(
    09368 => "oi",
    01234 => "tchau",
    34986 => "palavra",
    72494 => "abobrinha");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Dictionary.php).

Mantive os zeros não significativos, mas obviamente eles não são necessários