# Converter valor numérico em string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, valor-monetário

Estou criando um layout de recibo e preciso que o valor do recibo seja discriminado por extenso no corpo do recibo, por exemplo:

Transformar R$ 45,51 em Quarenta e Cinco reais e cinquenta e um centavos.

Existe alguma biblioteca que faça isso, e se não houver, alguma dica de como fazer isso na unha??

Comment: aqui um pacote no npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/extenso

Comment: rapaz... eu vi algo parecido a muito tempo atras, ve se é isso: http://jsfromhell.com/pt/string/extenso

Comment: a solução do @MarceloRafael é melhor! :)

Comment: @MarceloRafael, esse pacote do npm resolve o meu problema, muito obrigado por me indicar ele, e agradeço aos demais pela ajuda e colaboração...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Javascript não possui uma função nativa para realizar este processo.

Porém, Você pode utilizar esta função para retornar um número em extenso:

```
//+ Carlos R. L. Rodrigues
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/string/extenso [rev. #3]
String.prototype.extenso = function(c){
    var ex = [
        ["zero", "um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco", "seis", "sete", "oito", "nove", "dez", "onze", "doze", "treze", "quatorze", "quinze", "dezesseis", "dezessete", "dezoito", "dezenove"],
        ["dez", "vinte", "trinta", "quarenta", "cinqüenta", "sessenta", "setenta", "oitenta", "noventa"],
        ["cem", "cento", "duzentos", "trezentos", "quatrocentos", "quinhentos", "seiscentos", "setecentos", "oitocentos", "novecentos"],
        ["mil", "milhão", "bilhão", "trilhão", "quadrilhão", "quintilhão", "sextilhão", "setilhão", "octilhão", "nonilhão", "decilhão", "undecilhão", "dodecilhão", "tredecilhão", "quatrodecilhão", "quindecilhão", "sedecilhão", "septendecilhão", "octencilhão", "nonencilhão"]
    ];
    var a, n, v, i, n = this.replace(c ? /[^,\d]/g : /\D/g, "").split(","), e = " e ", $ = "real", d = "centavo", sl;
    for(var f = n.length - 1, l, j = -1, r = [], s = [], t = ""; ++j <= f; s = []){
        j && (n[j] = (("." + n[j]) * 1).toFixed(2).slice(2));
        if(!(a = (v = n[j]).slice((l = v.length) % 3).match(/\d{3}/g), v = l % 3 ? [v.slice(0, l % 3)] : [], v = a ? v.concat(a) : v).length) continue;
        for(a = -1, l = v.length; ++a < l; t = ""){
            if(!(i = v[a] * 1)) continue;
            i % 100 < 20 && (t += ex[0][i % 100]) ||
            i % 100 + 1 && (t += ex[1][(i % 100 / 10 >> 0) - 1] + (i % 10 ? e + ex[0][i % 10] : ""));
            s.push((i < 100 ? t : !(i % 100) ? ex[2][i == 100 ? 0 : i / 100 >> 0] : (ex[2][i / 100 >> 0] + e + t)) +
            ((t = l - a - 2) > -1 ? " " + (i > 1 && t > 0 ? ex[3][t].replace("ão", "ões") : ex[3][t]) : ""));
        }
        a = ((sl = s.length) > 1 ? (a = s.pop(), s.join(" ") + e + a) : s.join("") || ((!j && (n[j + 1] * 1 > 0) || r.length) ? "" : ex[0][0]));
        a && r.push(a + (c ? (" " + (v.join("") * 1 > 1 ? j ? d + "s" : (/0{6,}$/.test(n[0]) ? "de " : "") + $.replace("l", "is") : j ? d : $)) : ""));
    }
    return r.join(e);
}
```

Ela usa `String.prototype` por isso adiciona um método aplicado a todas as strings. Como por exemplo:

```
"123".extenso();
```

Como utilizar ela você pode ver aqui
Referência:

[JSFromHell](http://jsfromhell.com/pt/string/extenso)
resposta de: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5945/como-transformar-d%C3%ADgitos-num%C3%A9ricos-em-n%C3%BAmeros-por-extenso/5948#5948)

Comment: Copiou a mesma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5948/8063) da duplicada. Uma prática meio desonesta.

Comment: eu sinalizei que era duplicada junto com você @dvd, sempre faço isso. já que quem perguntou aqui não encontrou a duplicata antes ou talvez não entendeu, já que a pergunta vai ser fechada mesmo não vejo problemas em responde-la para ajudar quem perguntou, só que eu deveria ter colocado o link da resposta mesmo desta vez não me atentei e ficou parecendo um plagio muito feio. Meio desonesta ? como você disse "meia" é porque tem duvida se é ou não errado. Eu também tenho , mas como disse antes, pode ser que quem perguntou não tenha entendido a resposta na pergunta já feita no site

Comment: @dvd mas geralmente eu altero a resposta é que essa não deu tempo mesmo. Para não ficar 100% igual

Comment: Eu coloquei "meio" para amenizar um pouco o teor da frase, mas já que vc supõe que eu tinha alguma dúvida, eu retifico: acho totalmente desonesto. rs

Comment: @dvd mesmo colocando o link de onde eu tirei?

Comment: Sim. O correto era marcar como duplicata (blz, vc disse que fez isso) e não responder; ou poderia até responder se fosse uma outra resposta e não uma cópia fiel.

Comment: O correto nesse caso seria prestigiar uma resposta de um colega que já foi dada em outra questão igual.

Comment: Mas esquenta com isso não. Não estou questionando a sua honestidade. Sei que a intenção foi a melhor. Abs!

Comment: @dvd eu não sei como funciona se a pergunta marcada como duplicada é fechada e não aparece nas buscas dando oportunidade de "prestigiar" a pergunta feita em primeira mão, se funcionar assim vou manter a resposta, se não acho que devo tirar, de qualquer forma nas próximas já sei o que fazer :), ok obg