# Verificar elemento e substituir - repetição JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var test = new Array();

test["102-1"] = new Array("102-1", "Elemento");

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a[name='" + test["102-1"][0] + "']").attr({
        "data-original-title":test["102-1"][1]
    });
});
```

Este código verifica o elemento da página (no caso verifica o atributo 'name', dentro da tag a) e se ele for igual ao Array 'primeiro', ele acrescenta o atributo 'data-original-title' com as informações do Array 'primeiro' na posição [1].

Como posso melhorar esse código para ficar mais inteligente? Pois neste Array terá mais de 209 itens. Por exemplo:

```
test["102-1"] = new Array("102-1", "Elemento");
test["102-2"] = new Array("102-2", "Elemento");
test["102-3"] = new Array("102-3", "Elemento");
test["103-1"] = new Array("103-1", "Elemento");
... etc
```

E para isso terei que criar muitos

```
$("a[name='" + test["102-1"][0] + "']").attr({
    "data-original-title":test["102-1"][1]
});
```

Há alguma forma de reduzir, fazendo com que o código em JS verifique e repita os passos para substituir os itens certos pelo Array certo?

Abraços a todos!

Comment: Mas você tem todos os numeros escritos por extenso ? Tipo `test["duzentos e nove"]` ?

Comment: Tenho! Quero ver se há alguma possibilidade de não repetir a parte de substituição, no caso o `$("a[name='" + test["primeiro"][0] + "']").attr({
    "data-original-title":test["primeiro"][1]
});` Desta forma, futuramente, consigo mudar apenas as informações no Array ao invés de mudar o código todo e evitarei de deixar muito extenso também kkk...

Comment: Partindo por exemplo [desta conversão para numeros por extenso aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5945/como-transformar-d%C3%ADgitos-num%C3%A9ricos-em-n%C3%BAmeros-por-extenso) você já consegue transformar o seu código num `for` simples

Comment: Na verdade o que eu disse nem vai funcionar pois você tem o numero em ordinal, ou seja "primeiro", "segundo" e por ai, em vez de "um", "dois", etc.. Significa que primeiro tem que arranjar um código/biblioteca que faça essa conversão por si, e a partir desse ponto fica fácil.

Comment: Na verdade funcionaria sim! Usei 'primeiro', 'segundo', 'terceiro' como teste. Os números na verdade são '102-1', '102-2', '102-3', '103-1' etc...
Vou fazer novos testes. Tentar aplicar o 'for' para atribui os valores na página

Comment: Mas qual a necessidade de ter o numero por extenso então ? Parece me que você está a complicar. Não pode simplesmente usar o identificador que tem ?

Comment: Perdão! Editei e coloquei os números reais...

Comment: Qual é toda a gama de numeros que existem ? É sempre numero e `numero-1`, `numero-2` e `numero-3` ?

Comment: Isso nao tem um 'padrão'. Esses números é do GRI. Por exemplo, o padrão GRI 102 varia entre -1 á -56, porém não é sequencial. Do 102-18 pula para o 102-40.
Creio que a dificuldade nao seja nos números ou é? Minha ultima opção é fazer como no exemplo, escrever a mão para substituir os itens existentes na página.

Comment: Sem padrão não tem como automatizar, a menos que de alguma forma dê para saber quais estão na página por varrimento do JS.

Comment: Eu penso em fazer desta forma. Primeiro ele verifica os disponíveis e depois faz a mudança.
Mas por enquanto, tudo está indicando que terei que usar desta forma. Repetir o código duas vezes